# Why i can't declare ```var highScore = 0;``` inside for loop

Tags: javascript, variables

Hi when i try to declare `var highScore = 0;` inside `for loop` in chrome console it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'` so what can i do for that here is my code:

```
var scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54,
              58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69,
              34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51,
              69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61,
              46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18,
              41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];

var totalTest = scores.length;

function bubbleScore() {
  for (var i = 0; var highScore = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  console.log("Bubble solution #" + i + " score: " + scores[i]);
  if (scores[i] > highScore) {
    highScore = scores[i];
  }
  }
  console.log("Bubbles tests: " + scores.length);
  return console.log("Highest bubble score: " + highScore);
}
bubbleScore();
```

Comment: `var i = 0; var highScore = 0` should be `var i = 0, highScore = 0`

Comment: why so? i am learning by myself so i don't know that much please can you explain me do we have to declare only var keyword one time in for loop?

Comment: a `for` expression has only 3 parts, initialisation; end condition; increment. You have attempted to have 4 parts (2 initialisation), which is not valid You need to combine the two variable assignments to fit the way it is meant to be.

Comment: ok i got the right answer thanks!

Comment: Please keep in mind, if one of the answers works for you, please mark them as the answer to help other peeps in the community to find their solution easier if they facing the same issue. You can do this by using grey marks (tick) beside answers (you can only choose one), for more information please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 2):

As @Nick said earlier **`for` loop got three-section like `for (initialization; condition; post-expression)`** so the **thing you are trying here** (declaring two variables) **in the `for` loop is illegal**. Since **you want to iterate (and not defining it at the first of loop) your `highScore` variable in your `for` loop**, it is better to do it this way:

```
var highScore = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  console.log("Bubble solution #" + i + " score: " + scores[i]);
  if (scores[i] > highScore) {
    highScore = scores[i];
  }
}
```

But if you insist on such a thing you can do it like this:

```
for (var i = 0, highScore = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  console.log("Bubble solution #" + i + " score: " + scores[i]);
  if (scores[i] > highScore) {
    highScore = scores[i];
  }
}
```

Here is the full version:

```js
var scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54,
  58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69,
  34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51,
  69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61,
  46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18,
  41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44
];

var totalTest = scores.length;

function bubbleScore() {
  for (var i = 0, highScore = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    console.log("Bubble solution #" + i + " score: " + scores[i]);
    if (scores[i] > highScore) {
      highScore = scores[i];
    }
  }
  console.log("Bubbles tests: " + scores.length);
  return console.log("Highest bubble score: " + highScore);
}
bubbleScore();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use symbol `;` to declare
(*init conditions* `;` *continue condition* `;` *action after iteration*)

---

In this case it will be like

```
 for (var i = 0, highScore = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
```

or

```
for (let score of scores) {
```

---

*P.S to find max element try `Math.max(...scores);` or for old browsers `Math.max.apply(null, scores);`*

```
const scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54,
              58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69,
              34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51,
              69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61,
              46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18,
              41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];

function bubbleScore() {
  console.log("Bubbles tests: " + scores.length);
  return console.log("Highest bubble score: " + Math.max(...scores));
}
bubbleScore();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
var scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54,
              58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69,
              34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51,
              69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61,
              46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18,
              41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];

var totalTest = scores.length;
var highScore = 0;
function bubbleScore() {
  for (var i = 0; i < totalTest; i++) {
  console.log("Bubble solution #" + i + " score: " + scores[i]);
  if (scores[i] > highScore) {
    highScore = scores[i];
  }
  }
  console.log("Bubbles tests: " + scores.length);
  return console.log("Highest bubble score: " + highScore);
}
bubbleScore();
```